# Adding field dynamically

Tags: jquery

My situation is this ..
at the click of a link (add category) create a pair of select (category and subcategory) that populate with an ajax call.
The problem is that I have to do this n times I click on the link add category.
I tried this but it only works on the first:

```
$('.cat').change(function(){
             var Id =  $(this).val();          
             var url = Routing.generate('route_to_retrieve_subcategory');

            $.post(url, 
            { 'idCat': Id  
            }, function(results){
                var sub = $('.cat').parent().find('select[name*="[subCategory][]"]');
                sub.empty();
                $.each(results , function(key, value) { 
                    sub
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",value.id)
                    .text(value.subCategory));
                });
            });
});
```

Each select category has the class "cat".
How can I make this dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the on() function from jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.cat', function() {
     //your logic goes here...
});
```

This basically will bind any object that match the selector '.cat', on the event 'change' throughout the whole document